# flutter live audio plot illustration

Tags: flutter, audio, plot

What are the steps to create an "Audio waves" as an illustration to give visual feedback for the user in flutter?

[image]

I found this flutter package but I don't like the non - circular style of this widget:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_visualizers

Comment: two broad approaches are to plot the raw audio curve in its native format in the time domain (as an oscilloscope would show your voice) or send the audio into a FFT call to display the frequency domain representation where the energy intensity of each freq band is shown ... in either case you create a window of audio samples (a set of samples in time) then do the viz display then put that into a loop so it repeatedly shows a viz of the current audio

Comment: in either approach you need to gain access to the raw audio buffer which is what is being send into the library to render the raw audio into sound ... typically that happens in an event loop where this buffer can be plucked ... I know zero about flutter however all audio rendering uses this design pattern

Comment: look at https://github.com/iamSahdeep/FlutterVisualizers/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/sahdeepsingh/fluttervisualizers/FlutterVisualizersPlugin.java  specifically `              public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] waveform, int samplingRate) {`  which gains access to the raw audio buffer